# Create folder structure in JSTree programmatically

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am trying to recreate a folder structure in JSTree when user drops a file. Say, user drops files with file path "A\B\X.X", and "A\C\Y.Y", I want to create nodes with name A, B and C in jstree.

As of now, I am able to add nodes if they don't exist. If the node exists, I am unable to find the existing node. In above example, I can create nodes for A and B. But node "A" can't be found second time around.

Below is the code I have written till now.

```
 var folderList = path.split("/");
for (var i = 0; i < folderList.length - 1; i++) { //-1 to remove the file name from the folder name list
    var existingNodeID = '';
    //Check if node already exists
    var childrens = $("#js-tree").jstree("get_children_dom", parent);
    for (var j = 0; j < childrens.length; j++) {
        if (childrens[j].innerText == folderList[i]) {
            existingNodeID = childrens[j].id;
        }
    }
    //if node exists, select it as parent for the next loop
    if (!(existingNodeID === '')) {
        $('#js-tree').jstree().select_node(existingNodeID);
        parent = $("#js-tree").jstree('get_selected', true)[0].original;
    }
    else {
        //create a new node if there is no existing one
        var newNode = {
            id: generateUUID(),
            text: folderList[i],
            state: "open"
        };
        //Add node to jstree
        var sel = $("#js-tree").jstree().create_node(parent, newNode);
        //Select this node as parent for the next loop.
        parent = newNode.id;
    }
```

I am basically splitting the file path and creating node for each entry. This code is called in another loop for all the files.

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        //Add folder to JS Tree if it is not added
        createTreeNodeFromFilePath(files[i].fullPath, parent);
}
```

`parent` is the root node in the tree. Below is the code to find the existing sibling.

```
var childrens = $("#js-tree").jstree("get_children_dom", parent);
        for (var j = 0; j < childrens.length; j++) {
            if (childrens[j].innerText == folderList[i]) {
                existingNodeID = childrens[j].id;
            }
        }
```

Apparently this never finds any siblings. Say, I already have a node "A", and I have the id of the parent of "A", then this code should be able to get me the id of node "A".

Edit:

Updated the code. Below is a quick TL;DR.

**If node "A" has children nodes "B" and "C", I want to loop through those children of "A" and select the node based on the name.**

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out with one caveat.

```
//get list of all children of current parent node. returns an array of ids. 
    var childrens = $("#js-tree").jstree("get_node", parent).children_d;
    //check if childrens exist
    if (childrens) {
        //loop through the children list to find the existing child node with same name
        for (var j = 0; j < childrens.length; j++) {
            if ($("#js-tree").jstree("get_node", childrens[j]).text == folderList[i]) {
                existingNodeID = childrens[j];
            }
        }
```

`children_d` gives me a list of ids of all child nodes. Then inside the loop, I use `get_node` again to get the actual node reference. This works fine, and allows me to loop through all the child nodes to see if they exist. Rest of the code is unchanged from the question.

Now for the caveat. That `children_d` property returns all the child nodes of the child nodes too. So, if I have 1\2\3\4 as the tree, `children_d` of node 1 will return `[2,3,4]`. Basically, not just child, it is traversing through the whole child tree, as in children of the child nodes as well.

This should not be a big concern, as it is just unnecessary loop. But if there is a folder with same name inside a folder, then I get extra nodes created. So, 1\2\1\x.x works. But 1\1\2\1\x.x won't work.

Anyway, that is a different question altogether, which I can postpone for now.